# Fiscal year with concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below is currently the way I am calculating a fiscal year.

```
case when month(TimeOfCall) >= 4
then year(timeofcall) 
else year(timeofcall) -1
end as Fiscal
```

The output I am getting is this

```
 Fiscal
 2013
 2014
```

What I would like it to look like

```
Fiscal
2013/14
2014/15
```

Is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this with `CONCAT` and `RIGHT` function

```
Declare @SampleData as Table 
(
    timeofcall datetime   
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData Values ('2014-03-11'), ('2014-04-11')

SELECT 

CASE
  WHEN month(TimeOfCall) >= 4 
           THEN CONCAT(year(timeofcall), '/', RIGHT(year(timeofcall) + 1, 2))
  ELSE CONCAT(year(timeofcall) -1, '/', RIGHT(year(timeofcall), 2))
END as Fiscal

FROM @SampleData
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/KIBG33552

Comment: @Triv..How it 's return RIGHT(year(timeofcall), 2)---15 ?

Comment: Why not? i just added demo for it

Answer (score 0):

One method you can do that doesn't require `case` is:

```
select (datename(year, dateadd(month, -3, TimeOfCall)) + '/' +
        right(datename(year, dateadd(month, 12-3, TimeOfCall)), 2)
       ) as fiscalyear
```

Two important points:

- This uses date arithmetic to get the fiscal year -- by subtracting 3 months.
- This uses `datename()` to get the year as a string.